# Custom element child items

Tags: aurelia

I'd like to make a custom collapse element in my aurelia application.

This is how i'm trying it now:

Collapse element:

```
import { children, customElement } from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('collapse')
export class Collapse {
    @children('collapse-item') collapseItems;

    constructor() {
        console.log(this);
    }

    attached() {
        console.log(this);
    }

}
```

collapse item element:

```
import { noView, customElement, child } from 'aurelia-framework';

@noView
@customElement('collapse-item')
export class CollapseItem {
    @child('collape-item-header') header;
    @child('collape-item-body') body;
}
```

usage:

```
<collapse>
    <collapse-item>
        <collapse-item-header>Test Header</collapse-header>
        <collapse-item-body>Test Body</collapse-body>
    </collapse-item>
    <collapse-item>
        <collapse-item-header>Test Header 2</collapse-header>
        <collapse-item-body>Test Body 2</collapse-body>
    </collapse-item>
</collapse>
```

But its not working;

the collapseItems property in my Collapse instance is always undefined.

The next step would be to populate a bootstrap collapse using the data in the collapseItems array.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@child` and `@children` require `<slot></slot>`, so you cannot use `@noView`. Try this:

```
import { children, customElement, inlineView } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inlineView(`
  <template>
    <slot></slot>
  </template>
`)
@customElement('collapse')
export class Collapse {
  @children('collapse-item') collapseItems;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  attached() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

-

```
import { inlineView, customElement, child } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inlineView(`
  <template>
    <slot></slot>
  </template>
`)
@customElement('collapse-item')
export class CollapseItem {
  @child('collape-item-header') header;
  @child('collape-item-body') body;
}
```

Comment: Copy-pasted the example but the  @children attribute didn't work for me :(

Comment: Hm.. Could you provide a gist of what you're trying to do?